# CSS Text on an Image

Tags: css, css-float, css-position

I have the hardest time with CSS because it is so fickle it seems. Need to help with this.

I want my "section.png" image to be the Header Bar, which is clickable, and a table Expands and Collapses as you click the Header Bar.

```
<table width="100%">
 <tr>
 <td width=80% align=left>
 <font color="white" size="4"><strong>&nbsp;General Airport Information</strong></font>
 </td>
 <td align=right><font color="white" size="2">
    <div id='oc5' style="border-style: none; vertical-align:bottom;">
<img src="http://.../images/expand.png" width="15" height="15" style="border-style: none; vertical-align:top;">&nbsp;Show&nbsp;
</div></font>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

^^^
Everything in the "Div" above needs to be on top of the section.png image.
^^^

```
<div id="id5" style="display: none">    

<table width=80% align="center">
<tr align="left">
    <td colspan="2" align="right">
   Hidden text - Until Header Bar is Clicked.
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

I have looked around for answers, regarding this issue. I know it has to do with CSS and float or position and absolute or relative. IDK, I cant figure it out. Can someone steer me in the right direction.

Comment: you need the content expand and collapse onclick?

Comment: Your code seems to be incomplete - section.png does not actually appear in the markup. Also, there is no opening `<div>` tag in the first chunk.

Comment: <font> went out of use last CENTURY.

Comment: May I ask why you are using tables? Also the <font> tag was depreciated some years ago. And, try @sha404 answer by setting section.png as the background image of the parent div.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YaMhn/18/

Comment: Instead of the black background I want an image

Comment: Whats wrong with tables? And what do you use instead of font?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do this, would be to set a background instead of adding a image element

```
<div class="parent" style="background: url('image.jpg'); height: 300px; width: 500px;">
    <div class="text">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

No, not like this. if you want text on image, you should use the **section.png** as **div oc5**'s background image. and **expand.png** as **div id5**'s background image. you can set both in css file or in `<style>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

i think you put the text on the image

you can used position on as like this

**css**

```
.parent{
    position:relative;
    width:600px;
}

.child{position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    color:white;

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="child">This is dummy Text put here any text
        This is dummy Text put here any textThis is dummy Text put here any textThis is dummy Text put here any textThis is dummy Text put here any textThis is 
        dummy Text put here any textThis is dummy Text put here any textThis is dummy Text put here any textThis is dummy Text put here any text</div>
</div>
​
```

Live demo here http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/R82Ge/1/

Comment: <div style="position:relative; height:30px;width:100%; cursor:pointer;hand" onClick="showhide('id2'); return(false);"><img src=".../section.png" alt="" /><div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; color:white;">

Comment: ^^^^This solved it. One other question though. THe second div is slightly too close to the top of the image, how do I move it down about 2mm.?